# Creating a Y-shaped Recursive Tree

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

**Challenge**

In this challenge you will construct trees, in the form of ASCII Art using recursion. Basically you will generate the ASCII version of the [Fractal Tree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18785/create-a-fractal-tree)

**Input**

- Number of iterations `0 < N <= 5`

**Output**

- The `Nth` iteration of the Fractal Tree. It must be a matrix of 63 rows and 100 columns. (i.e. 6300 printable characters) It should be composed entirely of underscores and ones.

**Rules**

- Tree must be Y-shaped
- Input `0 < N <= 5`
- It must be a matrix of `63 rows` and `100 columns`
- It must be composed entirely of underscores `_` and ones `1`
- Do not include any extra leading or trailing spaces.

---

### Examples

**N = 1**

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
__________________________________1_____________________________1___________________________________
___________________________________1___________________________1____________________________________
____________________________________1_________________________1_____________________________________
_____________________________________1_______________________1______________________________________
______________________________________1_____________________1_______________________________________
_______________________________________1___________________1________________________________________
________________________________________1_________________1_________________________________________
_________________________________________1_______________1__________________________________________
__________________________________________1_____________1___________________________________________
___________________________________________1___________1____________________________________________
____________________________________________1_________1_____________________________________________
_____________________________________________1_______1______________________________________________
______________________________________________1_____1_______________________________________________
_______________________________________________1___1________________________________________________
________________________________________________1_1_________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
```

**N = 2**

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
__________________________1_____________1_________________1_____________1___________________________
___________________________1___________1___________________1___________1____________________________
____________________________1_________1_____________________1_________1_____________________________
_____________________________1_______1_______________________1_______1______________________________
______________________________1_____1_________________________1_____1_______________________________
_______________________________1___1___________________________1___1________________________________
________________________________1_1_____________________________1_1_________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
__________________________________1_____________________________1___________________________________
___________________________________1___________________________1____________________________________
____________________________________1_________________________1_____________________________________
_____________________________________1_______________________1______________________________________
______________________________________1_____________________1_______________________________________
_______________________________________1___________________1________________________________________
________________________________________1_________________1_________________________________________
_________________________________________1_______________1__________________________________________
__________________________________________1_____________1___________________________________________
___________________________________________1___________1____________________________________________
____________________________________________1_________1_____________________________________________
_____________________________________________1_______1______________________________________________
______________________________________________1_____1_______________________________________________
_______________________________________________1___1________________________________________________
________________________________________________1_1_________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
```

**N = 5**

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
__________________1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1___________________
___________________1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1____________________
___________________1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1___1____________________
____________________1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____1_1_____________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
_____________________1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1______________________
______________________1_____1_________1_____1_________1_____1_________1_____1_______________________
_______________________1___1___________1___1___________1___1___________1___1________________________
________________________1_1_____________1_1_____________1_1_____________1_1_________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
_________________________1_______________1_______________1_______________1__________________________
__________________________1_____________1_________________1_____________1___________________________
___________________________1___________1___________________1___________1____________________________
____________________________1_________1_____________________1_________1_____________________________
_____________________________1_______1_______________________1_______1______________________________
______________________________1_____1_________________________1_____1_______________________________
_______________________________1___1___________________________1___1________________________________
________________________________1_1_____________________________1_1_________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
_________________________________1_______________________________1__________________________________
__________________________________1_____________________________1___________________________________
___________________________________1___________________________1____________________________________
____________________________________1_________________________1_____________________________________
_____________________________________1_______________________1______________________________________
______________________________________1_____________________1_______________________________________
_______________________________________1___________________1________________________________________
________________________________________1_________________1_________________________________________
_________________________________________1_______________1__________________________________________
__________________________________________1_____________1___________________________________________
___________________________________________1___________1____________________________________________
____________________________________________1_________1_____________________________________________
_____________________________________________1_______1______________________________________________
______________________________________________1_____1_______________________________________________
_______________________________________________1___1________________________________________________
________________________________________________1_1_________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
_________________________________________________1__________________________________________________
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: The output format for this seems like a poor idea

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk that it where it gets complicated.

Comment: I think it'd be better if a smaller `n` was a smaller `Y`. Then you wouldn't need an upper bound on `n` or bounds for output width.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Why? (15 characters limit)

Comment: Not fully sure why this question is bounded at all. The bounding makes it less golfable because the only solution to this will be to hardcode "5". Would've been more interesting if you started small, explained the first 5 iterations, and didn't put a cap on it like mbomb noted. But I think that's a dupe of "create a tree" if I can find it...

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105840/binary-tree-fractal) (and imho how the challenge should've been written w/o bounding).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn How is the bound bad?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162979/simple-factorial-challenge#comment395032_162979).

Comment: @user202729 it's not *bad*, it's just **arbitrary** why 5? I'm guessing because OP didn't want to make iteration 6... Everything about this question (width of end ASCSII-art, height of end ASCII-art) is all bounded by the 5th iteration, which makes it (in my opinion, and it **is an opinion not a fact**) too constrained to be a good challenge...

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn sorry for the late answer. I took five because the initial size of the first tree is always going to be 16 lines. The next iterations get half size of the last iteration so the second iteration tree's get 8 lines, the third 4 lines, the fourth 2 lines and the fifth 1 line. After 5 iteration you can not draw any tree because `1/2 = 0.5` and you can not print in half line. Hope I was clear

Comment: This challenge is [from HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fractal-trees-all/)

Comment: @user9549915 *slowclap@OP*

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>902</s> <s>518</s> 472 bytes

```python
u='_';n='1';c=(31,47,55,59,62)[input()-1]
p=[u*100]*64+[u*18+'1_'*32+u*18]+[u*19+'1___'*15+n+u*20]*2+[u*20+'1_1_____'*8+u*16]+[u*21+(n+u*7)*8+u*15]*3+[u*22+(n+u*5+n+u*9)*4+u*14]+[u*23+('1___1'+u*11)*4+u*13]+[u*24+('1_1'+u*13)*4+u*12]+[u*25+(n+u*15)*4+u*11]*4
m=13;r=17
for x in range(26,33):p+=[u*x+n+u*m+n+u*r+n+u*m+n+u*(x+1)];m-=2;r+=2
p+=[u*33+n+u*31+n+u*34]*9
m=29
for x in range(34,49):p+=[u*x+n+u*m+n+u*(x+1)];m-=2
p+=[u*49+n+u*50]*16
print'\n'.join(p[:63-c]+p[-c:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDJbsMgEEDv/orc2OwqMwNOiMWXuCiqoi6uZIIsW0q/3jXgQ1T1AsN7swDxZ/66B1zXxbEr64JjwLqb4wS1PtXG1MbWLYp@CHGZuWjAV9H1i4Tj0ctWqxSeFYMrk4QqHXxmNrHrRsGosHHc0jEZPCaTXLLnVNLmEgTFU@ZJFGq8pMyx8NLHCqmT1aWGFM9zgCUIu6QidZZF0a6wKFN6gtkxeKmr0QF1k4NT9XGfDo/DEA7TW/h859jWROISVXr5I99jzOv0FPOHAuG7sXHYTcphVdKJsiUom/bSboPQ/p1Butb2vxlPffeW2mZhti@FtorTEGb2GtjL930IPPaXlpqbV7Fvbhcv1pV@AQ)

Needs a whole load of golfing but at least it works.